# React - Unexpected template string expression: no-template-curly-in-string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn React, and am following a video course to do so. I've entered in the code exactly as it appears on the screen..it's working in the video, but not for me.

Here is the code:

```
 <img alt='robot' src={'https://robohash.org/${props.id}?size=200x200'} />
```

It's telling my that the src is
'Unexpected template string expression: no-template-curly-in-string'

What is going on here? I'm using VSCode as my editor.

Comment: You should use ` instead of ' because of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#:~:text=Template%20literals%20are%20string%20literals,editions%20of%20the%20ES2015%20specification) if you want to add `${props.id}`.

Comment: template string uses ` ` instead of normal quotes

Comment: ah, ok, thank you! That wasn't explained in the tutorial I'm working through, and on their editor the quotes "literally" don't look any different with the font their editor is using. That did the trick!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

eslint caught ur mistake. which is template literal usage expression with `'`.

Mistake,

```
 <img alt='robot' src={'https://robohash.org/${props.id}?size=200x200'} />
```

```js
const props = {id: "someId"}
console.log('https://robohash.org/${props.id}?size=200x200')
```

Try, changing `'` with **`**,

```
 <img alt='robot' src={`https://robohash.org/${props.id}?size=200x200`} />
```

```js
const props = {id: "someId"}
console.log(`https://robohash.org/${props.id}?size=200x200`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `Template String` feature which can be used by `back-quote` at the first and end of your string.

Before:

```
 <img alt='robot' src={'https://robohash.org/${props.id}?size=200x200'} />
```

After:

```
 <img alt='robot' src={`https://robohash.org/${props.id}?size=200x200`} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so you have to use template literal.

So put this part below in back ticks i.e.  **`**

> `https://robohash.org/${props.id}?size=200x200`

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem,stupid use '' instead of `

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).